# when will be held 2013 election for moderators?

Tags: discussion

When will be election for moderators on drupal.stackexchange.com held in 2013. Any estimated date? last election was held in October 2012.

> On Stack Exchange, we believe the core moderators should come from the
>   community, and be elected by the community itself through popular
>   vote. We hold regular elections to determine who these community
>   moderators will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, moderator terms are indefinite. [Anna Lear's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155160/anna-lear) answer on  [Are moderators forever?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117633/are-moderators-forever)

> Moderators are elected for an indefinite term -- until either they ask
>   to step down or are asked to step down. Any moderator can be demoted
>   at any time at Stack Exchange's discretion.
>
> There is an absentee policy in the works, though it's not in effect
>   yet and may be subject to change:
>
> > Any moderator who is not active on the site for a period of six months is subject to removal of their moderator abilities.
> >     Moderatorship is an elected position, so if an absentee moderator
> >     returns to the site, they may be eligible for reinstatement.
>
> Moderators pro tempore (that is, moderators appointed by Stack
>   Exchange on new beta sites) are replaced when the first election
>   occurs. Unless, of course, they nominate themselves and get elected.
>
> An election is typically run when a moderator resigns or more
>   moderators are needed. Newly elected moderators join the existing ones
>   rather than replace them.
>
> Last but not least, some of the original trilogy moderators were
>   appointed before there was an election process in place. Their
>   appointments are also indefinite, at Stack Exchange's discretion.

Answer (score 1):

During 2012 there have been 2 elections already: The actual moderators have been elected all during 2012, and two moderators were elected during the last one.

For that reason, I don't think there will be any elections during 2013, if not for an exceptional reason.

Keep in mind that elections are held once per year, if there is really the need of new moderators. For *Stack Overflow*, there are two elections per year, but other sites don't even need an election per year, in some years.
Stack Exchange checks once per year if there is the need of new moderators, but that doesn't mean there could be more than one election, or none at all.